# Centered, forward and backward approximation

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

[image]

For these approximations, do we simply plug in the values? If someone could confirm, it would be highly appreciated

Comment: yes, it seems that way to me too

Comment: I mean at this point, this is basically a high school Algebra question unless if I'm going completely off track.

Comment: I'm getting 1/100 for centered approximation, -9/100 for forward approximation and 11/100 for backward approximation

Comment: can you provide a little bit of context to this problem? To me this is just basic introduction to derivatives?

Comment: In all three, only x is made specific, namely 0. The h must be kept as simply the variable h, and you compute as in usual algebra, and typically you may assume h is not 0 for the purpose of simplifying your results.

Comment: To @BraxtonParsons: Perhaps you may check your solutions with Python. See this resource: https://patrickwalls.github.io/mathematicalpython/differentiation/differentiation/

Comment: Yes, it looks to me that the question is just making sure you understand how to apply the formulae, which does reduce to basic algebra in the end.